# Can reducer containe instance variable in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I see example on Internet about `Reducer` has instance variables

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    private TreeMap<Integer, Long> counts = new TreeMap<Integer, Long>();

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        /* populate TreeMap */
    }
}
```

If one instance of `MyReducer` object is used to reduce multiple keys then we should clear `count` somewhere. Where should we do this? Or maybe one instance of `MyReducer` will be used for one `key`. If that key changes new instance will of `MyReducer` will be created. Is this correct? So the actual question is: How many `Reducer` object is created if we have one reducer task? one? or it is created per key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one instance of `Reducer` per task, not per key. Then, the `reduce` function is called once for each of the keys, so if after the shuffle one reducer has 4 keys, then its `reduce` function will be called 4 times.

As for that particular example of code, it does not need to clear the variable, since I guess it is storing the count of values for each of the keys. Since the function will be called once for each key, it will store in the `TreeMap` the count of each of them using the key as key for the `TreeMap`.